# Copy data from a table to another one has different structure

Tags: migrate

I have two tables with different structure:

TableSource:
intId(not null), txtSummary, strDetail

TableDesc:
guidId(not null), guidFK(not null), Name, Detail

I want to migrate data from two fields of tableSource(txtSummary, strDetail) to
two fields of tableDesc(Name, Detail).

guidId is auto generation and guidFK should be assigned to a fixed value.

I'v tried writing some t-sql code lines but not success. Could anyone help me?

Comment: What platform/DB software are you running? What have you tried and what does it mean by 'not working'?

Comment: I'm running on Sql Server 2005. I've written some t-sql code lines but  i'm not good at or experienced this. Both of tables are the same server but database.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
INSERT into TableDesc (Name, Detail)
SELECT txtSummary, strDetail
  FROM TableSource
```

should work, if the other fields are auto-generated on insert like you said.
Which database is this using?

Comment: May be you're right. But sorry, i can't suppose that guidFK is auto generation. It should be assigned to a value.

Comment: @Kernel - what do you want to assign it? A GUID generated at insert time, or else some other fixed value?